# Under what cases will I get iWork or iLife?

Tags: ios, mac, iwork, ilife

After looking at various models of Macs and looking at Apple's iLife and iWork pages, I'm more confused than where I started.

Originally, I thought that nothing - just Lion - came with a new Mac. But then I saw something [here](http://www.apple.com/ilife/) that says that iLife is a part of every new Mac.

So I thought. But then I saw [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1188319) that said that iLife is not a part of Lion. Huh? Then, to add to my confusion, I saw [this](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MB942Z/A?pqid=QKCD4PYYCFUJJ2PAHDYPCTK72CFHPPKXU), that said that iWork does not come with a new Mac. Hmm. So after doing some research, I've arrived at these conclusions:

- Apple really needs a central place to see what comes with a new Mac and what doesn't.
- iWork is seperate from iLife, but both can be bought from the Mac App Store.
- iLife comes with Lion.
- Nothing comes with iOS.
- I'm ***really*** confused.

So: Under what cases would I get iWork or iLife?

[example answer] You get iWork if you buy XYZ and iLife if you buy ABC. Both come on the Mac Pro, and none are on the iPad by default; however you can get iOS versions through the App Store for $41.34 each. You can buy them for $700 each on the MAS. The MacBook Air comes with iLife but not iWork; so does the MacBook Pro.

Comment: Why the downvote? As far as I can see, this is question both shows research effort and is clear and useful. If there's anything you found unsatisfactory about it, please explain and I'll fix it ASAP.

Comment: Macs ship with iLife, OS upgrades do not. All cost money on iOS. You appear to have researched yourself into a wet paper bag if you are spending $700 for iWork or iLife.

Comment: @bmike: That was an example - a humorous one at that - although I wouldn't be surprised if Apple decided to add iWork/iLife to the list of grotesquely overpriced objects (see their RAM prices).

Comment: The "central place to see what comes with a new Mac" is the "Included Software" section of the "Tech Specs" page for that Mac, e.g., here's the [iMac page](http://www.apple.com/imac/specs.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every new Mac (MBP, iMac, Mac Mini, MacBook Air, Mac Pro) purchased from Apple comes preinstalled with

- the latest version of Mac OS X
- the **latest version of iLife**
- **no iWork**

Every new iDevice has:

- the latest version of iOS
- **no iWork**
- **no iLife**

Every new copy of Lion has:

- Lion
- **no iWork**
- **no iLife**

Comment: What about iOS? What about a copy of Lion? Does iWork come with any Apple products?

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp iPhones and iPads do not come shipped with any of the mobile iLife and iWork apps. iWork of OSX has to be purchased separately for your Mac as well. Apple does not ship install DVDs anymore because you can recover your mac using the recover partition. However, you can also create your own [Lion recovery USB](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433).

Comment: It would be nice if Apple eventually creates the ability to tie iOS app purchases to Mac/OSX purchases.  For example, buying a Task List sort of app that has three versions–iPhone, iPad, and OSX, and get it on all three devices.  Or at a minimum, the developer could provide a license code in the app (or an email) that would transfer over to OSX.  I *don't* want to see a total merging of iOS with OSX; the BSD core of OSX makes it ideal for engineering, etc; OSX is the perfect desktop/laptop OS.  But tying app purchases together would be nice.

Comment: Also, hopefully with the OSX App Store, the ability to detect and offer discounts/upgrade prices on apps becomes possible.  I know many people were upset after having upgraded their expensive Pro apps (Final Cut, Logic, etc) and then having no upgrade option when they became app-store only.

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps OP is confused about what & why, and the answers above were lacking in detail although accurate.

Maybe this will help?

When you buy a new Mac, it will come with the current OS, and a free copy of iLife.

If you upgrade your OS at a later date, you're only buying the OS, so when iLife is updated you would need to buy that separately.

Mac apps and iOS apps are different, but they do have counterparts, such as the iWork apps. These are individual purchases on iOS, and not included with anything for free.

iWork isn't free with anything, and since the Mac app store, it's just the individual apps rather than the full suite, as is the case on the iOS app store.